# Declaring multiple alternative types instead of dynamic

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose I decorate a function like this so:

```
SomeType myFuntion( int x ) {
  . . .
}
```

Suppose, I'd like to make it polymorph and accept an int or a `String` as parameter `x`.

In this case I may declare `x` as `dynamic`. Unfortunately, the function shouldn't be that `dynamic`. It should **not accept any** typed value.

Q: May I somehow declare `( int | String )` as type alternatives?

Comment: [Dart does not support union types](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1222).  You can make `myFunction` take `dynamic` or `Object` and perform a *runtime* check that the argument is one of the allowed types, or you can make it take an argument of an intermediate type that allows itself to be initialized with only the desired types (e.g. `Either`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use Functional Programming with the help of the [Dartz package](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz).

```dart
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';

Either<int, String> doSomething(bool flag) {
  return flag ? Left(123) : Right("One Two Three");
}

void main() {
  final flags = [true, false];
  flags.map((flag) => doSomething(flag).fold(
      (myNum) => print('Got the number $myNum'),
      (myStr) => print('Got the string "$myStr"')));
}
```

Added benefit of this solution: you know which type (Left or Right) you get back from your function.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Dart doesn't support this. However, you could use extension methods to do something similar.

#### With Extension Methods

```dart
extension StringX on String {
  /// Used to do something on an `int` like this:
  ///
  /// ### Example
  /// 'SomeString'.myFunction()
  ///
  String myFunction() {
    // directly call any function you would normally call on a string
    // Below is the same as calling `this.substring...`
    return substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + substring(1);
  }
}

extension IntX on int {
  /// Used to do something on an `int` like this:
  ///
  /// ### Example
  /// 42.myFunction()
  ///
  SomeType myFunction() {
    return this *
        4; // `this` is a reference to the int this method was called on
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately not quite the stuff I'm in search of.